# A man sentenced to hibernation is released early and someone quips, "Good behavior" -- what was this from?

Tags: story-identification

I think this pretty funny scifi joke (I don't think I laugh at jokes in science fiction much) came from TekWars and a robot delivered it.

Note: I meant any one of book, film or tv show and now we know.

Comment: In TekWar the main character is released early from 'the freezer' and is accompanied by a robot, but nobody says that line.

Comment: @Valorum: And is the robot or the main character explosive? Seriously, if TekWar has someone released early from hibernation, I bet that line is there. I will try to find it. I have watched more than one movie and been baffled when something was different than I remembered, but films get edited. Let's see what I can find now that it does look like TekWar.

Comment: The novel was made into a TV show, a film and a graphic novel. You might be getting the line from one of those, maybe?

Comment: Not sure, but could be from `Demolition Man (1993)` with Sylvester Stallone and Wesley Snipes maybe?

Comment: @BdR but the question has been answered. The only thing in your suggestion is the hibernation as punishment.

Answer (score 10):

As Valorum points out, in TekWar the cop is released early from hibernation and his android partner makes the joke -- very deadpan delivery -- at 5:15 or so herein:

I believe that for some reason scifi does not lend itself to comedy -- I realize that there have been entire flicks that are scifi comedies -- but this line is not only a good one but considering how often the idea of sentencing a prisoner to suspended animation has come up, it is remarkable that it took so long for this joke to be made. If indeed it is original with TekWar, I would like to think that Bill Shatner came up with it; I know the book was ghostwritten, but I bet Shatner made some contributions.

Comment: A lot of Demolition Man (which came out the year before and also had a frozen cop getting released early) was rather amusing. Admittedly not as amusing as they were trying for, but ... it was OK.

Comment: @T.E.D. it definitely was supposed to be a comedy/thriller. with a genius like rob schneider, wtf do u mean it was not every bit as funny as they were trying?

Comment: You gotta at least admit that the "three seashells" thing has become a worldwide SciFi meme.

Comment: @T.E.D. The "Making copies" of Demolition Man.